# large area svg not scrolling

Tags: html, css, svg

I often want to use large svg's for data visualisation etc.  These are often big enough that you use the browser to scroll right and down to see everything like you would normally in a website.

The troubles started when I wanted to allow people to comment.  I first used foreignobject to embed html in the svg, but IE doesn't support this.  Then I turned to overlaying textareas over the svg using textareas and setting them to position:absolute. This way the text area sits nicely on top of the svg.

The only problem is that when the height of the svg exceeds that of the screen, the rest of the svg is not there, and can't be scrolled to.  I can zoom out which shows the svg, or adjust the viewbox to get the svg on screen. Neither of these are great solutions as I can't re-zoom to the bottom in the first instance, and lose my coordinates for the absolute textareas in the second. (If I can't figure this out, I will have to dynamically adjust their coordinates relative to the viewbox)

This isn't an overflow problem.  The height is a large number of pixels (eg 3000), so I am not asking the broswer to display anything outside of the svg borders.  I just want to be able to scroll.  Is that too much to ask :)

Apologies for the lack of code, svg's tend to be verbose...

Comment: there are lot of rendering issues in IE, scrolling by adjusting viewbox is a good idea...

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  Yes if it wasn't for IE I wouldn't be in this mess in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: fixed` to keep your comment box fixed when the SVG scrolls. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/LLre6fgk/

```
#comments {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

---

Then you can use `absolute` but with a container for your SVG and your DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/LLre6fgk/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <svg width="2000" height="2000">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#123" stroke-width="4" d="M0,0h50v50h50v50..."/>
    </svg>
    <div id="comments">
        <p>Please enter a comment:</p>
        <textarea cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Tolokoban.  Thanks for the suggestion.  The position relative to the svg is important to me though  (The svg provides the context for the comments that they will be entering.  The absolute tag is perfect for me- just broken :( )

Comment: Have you tried this update of mine? You now have the *absolute* tag and it scrolls.

Comment: Hi Tolokoban.  Thanks so much for your input.  I was convinced it was the textareas causing the problem.  Your answer showed me that the problem wasn't with them at all (since you have a working solution with position absolute), which led me to play around until I isolated the problem.  I would be happy to award the bounty to you except that yours isn't necessarily the answer to the problem.  Is there anyway to award it without marking it as correct?

Comment: I don't know how bouties gratifications work. But never mind: I'm happy to help and that's egnough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have found the problem.  And its name is jquery.fullPage.  I had this library included, but quickly decided not to use it.  (And then forgot to remove it)

This is how it describes itself: fullPage.js (is a) jQuery Plugin for fullscreen scrolling websites.

Perhaps unsurprisingly from that description, I should have guessed that it might impact the broader ability to scroll, even if it was not utilised in anyway.